# python inverting a dictionary of str:list of str

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to write a function that takes in a dictionary {name: [sports club]}, and inverts all values and returns a dictionary with inverted values {sports club: [names]}. For instance,

if the dictionary is:

```
name_to_club = {'Raymond Joe' : ['Volleyball', 'Football'], 'Joana Jackson': ['Gymnastics'], 'Anthony Jackson': ['Football', 'Basketball'], 'Sonia Smith': ['Gymnastics', 'Badminton']}
```

the function should return:

```
    {'Volleyball': ['Raymond Joe'], 'Gymnastics': ['Joana Jackson', 'Sonia Smith'], 'Basketball': ['Anthony Jackson'], 'Badminton': ['Sonia Smith'], 'Football': ['Raymond Joe', 'Anthony Jackson']}
```

I wrote a function below but it only returns one name for each sport, not every name that belongs in it. so it is giving:

```
{'Volleyball': ['Raymond Joe'], 'Gymnastics': ['Joana Jackson'], 'Basketball': ['Anthony Jackson'], 'Badminton': ['Sonia Smith'], 'Football': ['Raymond Joe']}
```

I cannot seem to include every person that belong to the same sports club, and I am only a beginner in python so I would appreciate any help without complicating it!

```
def club_to_name(name_to_club):
    lst = []
    dic = {}

    for value in name_to_club.values():
        for c in value:
            if c not in lst:
                lst.append(c)
                new = set(lst)
                for eachitem in new:
                    for key, value in name_to_club.items():
                        if eachitem in value:
                            dic.update({eachitem:[key]})                         
    return dic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2014, 13:22:43) 
>>> name_to_club = {'Raymond Joe' : ['Volleyball', 'Football'], 'Joana Jackson': ['Gymnastics'], 'Anthony Jackson': ['Football', 'Basketball'], 'Sonia Smith': ['Gymnastics', 'Badminton']}
>>> result = {}
>>> for name, sports in name_to_club.items():
...     for sport in sports:
...             result.setdefault(sport, []).append(name)
... 
>>> result
{'Basketball': ['Anthony Jackson'], 'Football': ['Raymond Joe', 'Anthony Jackson'], 'Badminton': ['Sonia Smith'], 'Gymnastics': ['Sonia Smith', 'Joana Jackson'], 'Volleyball': ['Raymond Joe']}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation using defaultdict and sets

```
from collections import defaultdict

name_to_club = {'Raymond Joe' : ['Volleyball', 'Football'], 'Joana Jackson': ['Gymnastics'], 'Anthony Jackson': ['Football', 'Basketball'], 'Sonia Smith': ['Gymnastics', 'Badminton']}
inverted = defaultdict(set)
for name, sports in name_to_club.items():
    for sport in sports
        inverted.add(name)
```